# webview textsize for different screen resolution

Tags: android, webview

I am implementing web view in my android application for getting dynamic text. But the problem is text size is bigger/small in different screen sizes. How to resolve this problem? I am using like this..

```
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static int dp2px(Context context, float dpVal){
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dpVal, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(dp2px(context,20)/webview.getScale());
or:
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(dp2px(context,20)*webview.getScale());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, text size(20) is bigger/small in  same hdpi screens

Comment: What about other icons in same hdpi screens

Comment: problem with only text size, except that everything is fine.

Comment: What about  Image in Webview in same hdpi screens

Comment: problem with image size(bigger/smaller in hdpi devices) also.

Comment: I have no idea now. Does Not working mean webview.getScale() is same in devices ?

Comment: I understand one problem that is, in android 4.4 versions the text size is very small it size. But in android 5.0 or later it is working fine. Any solution for this?

Comment: I think is not about 4.4 or 5.0 , is about screenSize and dpi.

Answer (score 0):

You should make you're font size a px (pixels) or dp (Density-independent pixels).  Just use pixels, because it will always be 20 pixels on each screen and won't change.  If you use dp, the screen size will vary on the density of pixels and the text size can change.   So your code will look like this

```
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(20px);
```

Read this: [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is giving error when i mention "px"